# ASP.NET MVC Controller design

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's have an oject structure like this :

Company -> Department -> Person

-> means 1:M relation

Should I have one fat controller which serves all request for this objects or one controller per every object ?

There will be the usual CRUD operations for each object. The details (Department,Person) will be displayed on one page using grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct relationship between your data model and your controllers. I view controllers as groupings of related functionality, from the prespective of the application. What I mean is that I typically create a controller for each big logical chunck of functionality. So if I were creating a contacts MVC web app, I might have:

- AccountController (*for authentication/authorization*)
- ContactsController (*for the real business case, contacts*)
- AdminController (*for super users to modify the app*)

By in my data model I might have tables like, User, Contact, Address, Phone, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If its like an admin type thing, I would just use a single controller or use dynamic data. Otherwise I like to breakdown my controllers based on behavior for example, Room Booking, Time-sheet management etc.

Answer (score 2):

Following DDD - if only Company is aggregate root - then one (but still **thin**) controller

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with one controller per object per CRUD ... so one controller for Department and one for Person.  Why?

You should either have a DTO or Repository for each.  If you have a repository:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private IPersonRepository _personRepository;
    public PersonController(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }
}
```

Then use an IoC container (I like [StructureMap](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/02/27/Using-StructureMap-with-the-ASPNET-MVC-framework.aspx)) for the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a separate controller for each.  If one controller (like company) has to pull people information that is fine.

If you really want [Render Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).  This lets you view call into another controller to load that part of the view.